# factory bot - would like to define an attribute in terms of another attributes attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have the following User class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
```

and the following factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :site_report_request do
    site_report
    user(company: site_report.site.company)
  end
end
```

but the `user(company:...` is causing me an error.

I have also tried:

```
association :user, factory: :user, company: site_report.site.company
```

and

```
association :user, factory: :user, company: self.site_report.site.company
```

This seems pretty straightforward but I can't find an example (easily) in the docs. How would I make the user's company the same as the value created in site_report's site?

Comment: Try using [`after(:build)`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks) callback

Answer (score 0):

You can try by passing an explicit block on the `user` association:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :site_report_request do
    site_report
    user { create(:user, company: site_report.site.company) }
  end
end
```